# return empty List in catch block

Tags: c#, .net, return-value, return-type

I have a c# function that reads file locations from a Datatable, and returns a List with all the file lcoations to the calling method.

In the `Catch` block, I want to return an empty list with a false so teh calling method can cancel it's operation.

But I can't get my `return` statement to compile.

Would it be better to pass in a list as a refernce, and have the function return a boolean `true/false`?

here is the code I am trying:

```
   public static List<string> getEmailAttachments(string emailID, System.Data.DataTable emails)
    {
        List<string> allAttachments;

        //System.Data.DataTable oTbl = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();

            var results = from myRow in emails.AsEnumerable()
                          where myRow.Field<string>("itemID") == emailID
                          select myRow;

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("attachments");
            foreach (DataRow myRow in results)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(myRow.Field<string>("attachmentsPath"));
                allAttachments.Add(myRow.Field<string>("attachmentsPath"));

                //DataTable dt = (DataTable)myRow["attachmentsPath"];
                //DataTable oTbl = dt.Clone();

                //DataRow[] orderRows = dt.Select("CustomerID = 2");

                //foreach (DataRow dr in orderRows)
                //{
                //    oTbl.ImportRow(dr);
                //}
                // myTable.ImportRow(dr);
                //oTbl.Rows.Add(myRow);
                //oTbl.ImportRow(myRow);
            }

            return allAttachments;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logBuilder("common.getEmailAttachments", "Exception", "", ex.Message, "");

            return new List<string>emptyList(); // cannot compile
        }
    }
```

Comment: Side question - what type of exceptions you have with this code? Maybe you can handle these cases without involving exceptions?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Change this line:

```
return new List<string>emptyList(); // cannot compile
```

to:

```
 return new List<string>();
```

Passing a list as a refernce, and returning a boolean value from the function, it is a bad idea. Your method called `getEmailAttachments`, it's load attachments, and it should return attachments. If you want to check the result of loading attachments, i can suggest you return `null` and check the returned value.

Comment: well, really perhaps the name is not perfect, it could be called `getEmailAttachmentPaths` ...do you think I would be better off passing in a `ref` string array instead of a list?

Comment: No `List` is ok, and I repeat again passing `ref` parameters in your case it's a bad idea.

Comment: yes, I've changed it to return a list, and no `ref` params, as I can just check the size of the list returned...(DOH)

Comment: perhaps it better to not catch... and handle on the caller. after all it was an exception.

Answer (score 41):

If someone still looking...

Use `IEnumerable<string>` as return type and:

```
return Enumerable.Empty<string>();
```

Comment: Underrated solution this one

Comment: This is actually the correct solution to throwing empty lists

Comment: This should be accepted answer but in case you are returning Array or IEnumerable. But when i tried this with List return type it didn't let me do that so i had to add .ToList();

Answer (score 5):

I would take a slightly different approach. 
I would return an empty list but ALSO set the initial capacity to ZERO!

Like this:

```
return new List<string>(0);//notice the initial capacity to zero.
```

The reason is for memory consumption and optimization... I know it is a micro optimization but it won't hurt anything. It might actually benefit the overall application.

Answer (score 5):

A better way has been added since around .Net Framework 4.6 and in the Core .Net versions,

```
return Array.Empty<T>();
```

This allocates a single array (which is an IList) and reuses it for all subsequent requests for an empty array of that type.  Its fast, and clean.

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
 return new List<string>();
```

Answer (score 2):

try this..

```
public static List<string> getEmailAttachments(string emailID, System.Data.DataTable emails)
    {
        List<string> allAttachments;

        //System.Data.DataTable oTbl = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();

            var results = from myRow in emails.AsEnumerable()
                          where myRow.Field<string>("itemID") == emailID
                          select myRow;

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("attachments");
            foreach (DataRow myRow in results)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(myRow.Field<string>("attachmentsPath"));
                allAttachments.Add(myRow.Field<string>("attachmentsPath"));

                //DataTable dt = (DataTable)myRow["attachmentsPath"];
                //DataTable oTbl = dt.Clone();

                //DataRow[] orderRows = dt.Select("CustomerID = 2");

                //foreach (DataRow dr in orderRows)
                //{
                //    oTbl.ImportRow(dr);
                //}
                // myTable.ImportRow(dr);
                //oTbl.Rows.Add(myRow);
                //oTbl.ImportRow(myRow);
            }

            //return allAttachments;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logBuilder("common.getEmailAttachments", "Exception", "", ex.Message, "");

            allAttachments= new List<string>();
        }
        return allAttachments;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

what about

```
allAttachments.Clear();

return allAttachments;
```

Comment: what about `while (true) { if (!allAttachments.Any()) return allAttachments; allAttachments.RemoveAt(0); }`

Comment: @Sergey `while(true)` is infinite loop,  is it an alternative answer or....crashing algorithm?

Comment: I just pointing that there is no need to logically connect empty list with list being filled in `try` block. When I would see this code, I would wonder why its important to return `allAttachments` instance - is it passed by reference? So, I would not add some error-handling operations on `allAttachments` list, or if you want to confuse developers, then loop is a nice option :)

Answer (score 0):

Anyone still looking? Try this instead:
Change the return type of your method and use the below code.
Also, change the CartItemDTO class and replace it with the one that suits your code

```
return Enumerable.Empty<CartItemDTO>().ToList()
```